# Display results of join query in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

I'm having a bit of a struggle displaying results from a query in a blade template.  The basics:  I have two tables; countries and issuers.  The Country model has a hasMany relation to Issuer, and vice versa.  Both relations are properly defined in the models.  I am trying to display a list of issuers that contains the name (nation) of the country as well.  My query, in the IssuersController, is as follows:

```
      $issuers = ISSUER::join('countries', 'issuers.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
             ->select('issuers.*', 'countries.nation')
             ->orderBy('nation', 'asc')
             ->orderBy('author', 'asc')
             ->get();
```

This query works and dd(); shows it returning an array for each issuer that includes all of the issuer data as well as the corresponding country name as nation.  Perfect.  However, when I attempt to display this in my view I run into a wall.  My first attempt was to just use

```
                      @foreach($issuers as $issuer)
                   <tr>
                     <td>{{ $issuer->id }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $issuer->nation }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $issuers->author }}</td>
```

This returns an undefined variable on $nation.  I'm not sure why this happens as I'm not attempting to access the relationship.  I'm simply trying to access the results of an array that was returned from the query.  The relationship should not be relevant at that point.  Anyway, attempting to use the relationship I try

```
                      @foreach($issuers as $issuer)
                   <tr>
                     <td>{{ $issuer->id }}</td>
                     @foreach($issuer->nation as $nation)
                     <td>{{ $issuer->nation }}</td>
                     @endforeach
                     <td>{{ $issuers->author }}</td>
```

Which returns and invalid argument supplied in foreach() error.  Next I attempt to use the method...

```
                      @foreach($issuers as $issuer)
                   <tr>
                     <td>{{ $issuer->id }}</td>
                     @foreach($issuer->Country() as $nation)
                     <td>{{ $issuer->nation }}</td>
                     @endforeach
                     <td>{{ $issuers->author }}</td>
```

This throws no error but also returns nothing.  The colum is simply skipped and everything else that is echoed gets shifted one column to the left.

I'm sort of lost here and I think it's because my brain is stubbornly holding on to the idea that I'm accessing elements of a query result rather than elements of a relationship, so I can't quite figure out why I need a separate loop for that one column, or how that loop should work.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Changed the last part because I typed it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this for anyone that stumbles upon it later.  I was able to access the value of nation directly from the query result without the model relation by changing the query from

```
->select('issuers.*', 'countries.nation')
```

to

```
->select('issuers.*', 'countries.nation as nation')
```

From their I simply accessed the value as I would everything else:

```
                 <td>{{ $issuer->id }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $issuer->nation }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $issuers->author }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Change this

$issuers = ISSUER::join('countries', 'issuers.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
             ->select('issuers.*', 'countries.nation')
             ->orderBy('nation', 'asc')
             ->orderBy('author', 'asc')
             ->get();
TO

$issuers = ISSUER::
                 ->join('countries', 'issuers.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
                 ->derBy('nation', 'asc')
                 ->orderBy('author', 'asc')
                 ->get();

    Get all the content in your Blade like this

    {{ $issuers ['type_the_name_of_the_column_you_want_to_display'] }}
```