# How to create subrow in one column dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, laravel-blade

In this image this table is based on my databse "Employee" table. there is 2 part. 1st part is from "#" column to "employee type" column. 2nd part is "Leave Type" Column. This column infromation will come from "LeaveType" Table. No I want to create different type leavetype for 1 employee. It mean I want to create subrow for each parent row in this column. But I can't
[image: table image]

here is my incomplete table code in blade file.

```
<table class="table table-bordered mb-0" id="myTable">
    <thead class="bg-orange">
    <tr class="text-light">
        <th >#</th>
        <th >Employee Name</th>
        <th >Employee Id</th>
        <th >Employee Type</th>
        <th >Leave Type</th>
        <th >Entitled</th>
        <th >Used Leave</th>
        <th >Balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
            <td>
                {{$user->name}} <br>
                @foreach($designations as $designation)
                @if($designation->id === $user->designationId)
                {{$designation->designationName}}
                <br>
                @endif
                @endforeach

                @foreach($departments as $department)
                @if($department->id === $user->departmentId)
                {{$department->departmentName}}
                @endif
                @endforeach

            </td>
            <td>{{$user->employeeId}}</td>

            @foreach($designations as $designation)
                @if($designation->id === $user->designationId)
                 <td>{{$designation->attendanceType}}</td>
                <br>
                @endif
            @endforeach
                <td>

                </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where is your select? there yoin join the second table and add the subtyoe in the select instead of the origianal

Comment: i dont use any join query. Just suppose if i want to make more subrow in blue marked column in this picture what should i do

Comment: then you should use it, it makes the life easier

Comment: then what should we do after this

Comment: after joing all tables you have **one** array where all the information is stored and you cann access it like you already did

Comment: then how can i create table row in a box thats my question

Comment: please take soe time to research a quick search revelas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022216/display-results-of-join-query-in-blade where every thing explained for two tables and then add a third table the rest follows